# Problems running MWC application for WP7

Tags: xamarin

I started with Xamarin just a couple weeks ago and downloaded the sample applications from the official site and start looking for some cross-platform examples, especially in the database field.
But I can´t get the MWC application to work on WP7 (VS2010). It shows me the following errors:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'Community.CsharpSqlite.Sqlite3.sqlite3_open(string, ref Community.CsharpSqlite.Sqlite3.sqlite3)' has some invalid arguments   
File: SQLite.cs 
Line: 2497  
Project:MWC.Core.WP7
```

```
The best overloaded method match for 'Community.CsharpSqlite.Sqlite3.sqlite3_open_v2(string, ref Community.CsharpSqlite.Sqlite3.sqlite3, int, string)' has some invalid arguments
File:    SQLite.cs  
Line:    2502
Project: MWC.Core.WP7
```

Among others...

I already installed the Xamarin trial, and the Windows Phone SDK.
I´m missing somethig here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add the code where you are calling this method?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the latest code from the [SqlLite.net project website.](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) ?